# how to return error from async/await inside promises

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

i initially wrote the code with promises, but due to a for loop had to use async/await.

the code works now, but i don't know how to throw the error which can work equivalent to reject of promise.

```
let createGroup=(data)=>{
                return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                    if(check.isEmpty(data.groupName)){
                        reject('GroupId not Valid');
                    }
                    else{
                        let newGroup= new ExpenseModel({
                            groupId:'G-'+shortid.generate(),
                            groupName:data.groupName,
                            contributors:data.contributorObjIds,
                            timeCreated:time.now().format(),
                            creator:data.ownerId
                        })
                        newGroup.save((err,group)=>{
                            if(err){
                                reject(`Group Not Created ${err}`);
                            }else{
                                data.groupdata=group;
                                console.log("group created",data);
                                resolve(data);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }

            let updateUserData= async (data)=>{
                try{
                    for(user of data.contributorIds){
                        const res=await UserModel.findOne({'userId':user});
                        res.groups.push(data.groupdata._id);
                        const resSave=await res.save();
                        let id='GroupCreated'+user;

                        eventEmitter.emit('getGroup',user);    
                    }

                    return 1;
                }
                catch(e){
                    return e;
                }
            }



            createGroup(data)
            .then(updateUserData)
            .then((resolve)=>{
                let apiResponse = response.generate(false, 'Group created', 200, resolve);
                console.log(apiResponse);
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                let apiResponse = response.generate(true, 'Group not saved', 400, null);
                console.log('group creation failed',err);
                 res.send(apiResponse);
            })
```

here in **updateUserData** how to check for errors while fetching data from db.
so that it finally goes to the catch block of the promise. and **apiResponse** of error is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i don't know how to throw the error which can work equivalent to reject of promise.

Well, you should `throw` it not `return` it :-) Exceptions in an `async function` will cause the returned promise to reject.

```
async function updateUserData(data) {
    try {
        for (user of data.contributorIds) {
            const res = await UserModel.findOne({'userId':user});
            res.groups.push(data.groupdata._id);
            const resSave = await res.save();
            let id = 'GroupCreated'+user;
            eventEmitter.emit('getGroup', user);
        }
        return 1;
    } catch(e){
        throw e;
//      ^^^^^
    }
}
```

However, catching an error with `try`/`catch` only to rethrow it without doing anything else is pointless, you should just let the exception bubble. Simplify to

```
async function updateUserData(data) {
    for (user of data.contributorIds) {
        const res = await UserModel.findOne({'userId':user});
        res.groups.push(data.groupdata._id);
        const resSave = await res.save();
        let id = 'GroupCreated'+user;
        eventEmitter.emit('getGroup', user);
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: hi Bergi, is that **return 1** needed in the try statement to exit async after for() is complete?

Comment: No, it's not needed to exit the function, unless you want your promise to fulfill with 1. If an async function exits without any `return` statements, then as usually it works as if it had a `return undefined` statement, and the promise is fulfilled with `undefined`.